# Karma test runner spams output when one test fails

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I am using the karma test runner for testing AngularJs controllers etc. (Windows 7, phantomJs)

When running the tests on my machine i get a line in the output for each test that has been run. e.g.:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.1 (Windows 7): Executed 156 of 201 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.423 secs
PhantomJS 1.9.1 (Windows 7): Executed 157 of 201 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.425 secs
PhantomJS 1.9.1 (Windows 7): Executed 158 of 201 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.426 secs
PhantomJS 1.9.1 (Windows 7): Executed 159 of 201 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.427 secs
PhantomJS 1.9.1 (Windows 7): Executed 160 of 201 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.429 secs
PhantomJS 1.9.1 (Windows 7): Executed 161 of 201 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.43 secs)
PhantomJS 1.9.1 (Windows 7): Executed 162 of 201 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.432 secs
PhantomJS 1.9.1 (Windows 7): Executed 163 of 201 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.433 secs
PhantomJS 1.9.1 (Windows 7): Executed 164 of 201 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.434 secs
PhantomJS 1.9.1 (Windows 7): Executed 165 of 201 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.436 secs
PhantomJS 1.9.1 (Windows 7): Executed 166 of 201 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.437 secs
PhantomJS 1.9.1 (Windows 7): Executed 167 of 201 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.438 secs
```

This is very annoying since I have to scroll a long way up to see the actual error in the 1 failing test. 
We are three people running the same solution and the same karma.conf file. Two of us experience this problem. The other doesn't.

So far I tried reinstalling karma to no avail. Is there some environment setting I have screwed up or something?

Comment: I've noticed this, but on the newer versions of Karma. You could try downgrading?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by changing my karma.config.js file to having 'dots' reporting. I don't really like the change in styles, put my terminal is no longer pages long when a test fails.

My old option:

```
reporters: ['progress']
```

My new option:

```
reporters: ['dots']
```